# Downloading and renaming images using python

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to download and rename images from a from a website using this code-

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

df = pd.read_excel("images.xlsx")
data = df.to_dict()
for i in range(0, len(data['ITEMS'])):
    try:
        for url in data['IMAGES'][i].split(","):
            ext = "." +data['IMAGES'][i].split(".")[-1]
            r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
            open(data['ITEMS'][i]+ext, 'wb').write(r.content)
        continue
    except:
        continue
```

But it is not downloading and renaming

Here is one images link I am sharing, of that website-
[Image](https://www.sephora.ae/dw/image/v2/BCVW_PRD/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-masterCatalog_Sephora/default/dwcc832822/images/hi-res/SKU/SKU_1247/479731_swatch.jpg)

And for other websites it is working.

Please tell me why it is not working on this website and what is the solution for this

Thank you

Comment: Please add `print(r.status_code)` immediately after `r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)`, run your code and write what it did printed.

Comment: @Daweo The code is running but nothing is printing sir

Comment: so either `data['IMAGES'][i].split(",")` is empty or error is raised which is then caught be `try`-`except` and ignored. Please try removing `try`-`except`, run and check if any error or exception appears.

Comment: @Daweo now I have written like this,

`import pandas as pd`
`import requests`

`df = pd.read_excel("images.xlsx")`
`data = df.to_dict()`
`for i in range(0, len(data['ITEMS'])):` 
      `url in data['IMAGES'][i].split(",")`
      `ext = "." +data['IMAGES'][i].split(".")[-1]`
      `r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)`
      `open(data['ITEMS'][i]+ext, 'wb').write(r.content)`    

Then error is coming

`File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\images\run.py", line 10, in <module>`
    `url in data['IMAGES'][i].split(",")`
`NameError: name 'url' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access your link with a browser but it doesn't work, fix it and make sure that it is accessible before trying to download resources using python.

Comment: I could access it in a browser, but via requests the download loads forever so i specified a timeout. However the .get command does not work - probably some kind of safety feature from the webserver or similar.

Comment: @mourad please use UAE vpn, because this site is of UAE, mostly countries it is not opening.

Comment: @matle for every website it is working. I am using this code from last 6  months. but only in this website. This problem is coming

Comment: maybe you are using some kind of filtering because in my case it's not responding (no response data) maybe the firewall is preventing the web server to send responses and you are behind the firewall that's why you get the response. i don't know but be sure that i am not getting a response from your server. ask someone else to test for you and make sure that he is not in the same Intranet.

Comment: @MouradGHERSA Sure sir, that only I am doing, I have tried so many things but unable to do that. But thanks

Comment: use localtunnel to expose your server https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel i am not allowed to use a VPN.

Comment: @MouradGHERSA I have created a virtual server here sir. then also the same problem is coming. Even when I am using the image link as CDN. it is not appearing there.